# How to run multi-tag selector

Tags: dbt

I am using dbt 0.18.1 and I follow the documentation about tags however I am curious to know how to run multi-tag selector as arguments.
According to this:
https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/pull/1014

> Select using a mix of tags, fqns, and parent/child selectors:
> $ dbt run --model tag:nightly+ salesforce.*+

Unfortunately this is not really a "mix of tags". 
I have tags of [mixpanel_tests, quality] and I wish to run models that have both tags included (not separated). If I run `dbt run -m tag:quality -t blabla`

1. I would have executed all models that have QUALITY in the array of tags regardless if its single argument or multiple argument however I wish to run ONLY quality marked. How to do that?
2. How do I specify 2 tags or 3 tags selector to run models with the mentioned tags (i.e mixpanel_tests, quality - but only those models that have both tags defined). More or less an AND clause rather than an OR clause.

   Hmm I hope it is clear. How to have multitag selector that executes only the combination of tags given?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the [intersection operator](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/set-operators/#intersections). It's new in dbt v0.18, and it's for this use case exactly.

```
dbt run -m tag:mixpanel_tests,tag:quality
```